# Gcc error when installing psycopg2 into a virtualenv (Lubuntu 12.04, python 2.7)

Tags: python, postgresql, virtualenv

I'm trying to install psycopg2 into a virtualenv using pip but there seems to be some kind of gcc error that I can't get my head around. I've installed python-dev and libpq-dev as suggested by some other questions.

```
pip install psycopg2
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/mdang/Dropbox/WebDev/ideas/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/mdang/Dropbox/WebDev/ideas/venv/build/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-SBgH20-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/mdang/Dropbox/WebDev/ideas/venv/include/site/python2.7:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement

gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /home/mdang/Dropbox/WebDev/ideas/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/mdang/Dropbox/WebDev/ideas/venv/build/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-SBgH20-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/mdang/Dropbox/WebDev/ideas/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/mdang/Dropbox/WebDev/ideas/venv/build/psycopg2
Storing complete log in /home/mdang/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: It came installed with Ubuntu. I tried reinstalling with synaptic but that didn't change anything. Do I need to do something with setting up gcc in the virtualenv?

Answer (score 2):

Edit your sources.list file (normally found in `etc/apt/sources.list`) and add a `deb-src` for each corresponding `deb` line.

> deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
>
> deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted **#Add this line**
>
> deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
>
> deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted **#Add this line**

The difference between the two:

- `deb`: These repositories contain binaries or precompiled packages.
  These repositories are required for most users.
- `deb-src`: These repositories contain the source code of the
  packages. Useful for developers.

Now try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep psycopg2  # The name has changed to `psycopg2` from `python-psycopg2`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install two things:

1. `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
2. `sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2`

The first installs the necessary build tools you need, and the second installs the dependencies you need to compile psycopg2 inside a virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried your solution and it said build-essentials was up to date and: Unable to find a source package for psycopg2.