# E: Unable to find a source package for psycopg2 or use pip with virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip, psycopg2

I'm having trouble setting up psycopg2 w/pip & virtual env so I can launch django apps on heroku.

I'm currently trying to follow this [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489609/gcc-error-when-installing-psycopg2-into-a-virtualenv-lubuntu-12-04-python-2-7) to solve my issue (below) but I'm stuck at trying to run this command,

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2
```

I get this error

```
ahmad@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get build-dep psycopg2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for psycopg2
ahmad@ubuntu:~$
```

... not sure what to do about this? How can I help it find the source package for psycopg2...

I've tried running this

```
apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
```

and i get

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
```

The reason I'm trying to get that installed is so I can run pip install psycopg2 without getting all these gcc errors (see sample run below)

```
(venv)ahmad@ubuntu:~/workspace/dogood$ pip install Django psycopg2 dj-database-url
Downloading/unpacking Django
  Downloading Django-1.4.3.tar.gz (7.7Mb): 7.7Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Django

Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.4.6.tar.gz (667Kb): 667Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
Downloading/unpacking dj-database-url
  Downloading dj-database-url-0.2.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package dj-database-url

Installing collected packages: Django, psycopg2, dj-database-url
  Running setup.py install for Django
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/django-admin.py from 664 to 775

    changing mode of /home/ahmad/workspace/dogood/venv/bin/django-admin.py to 775
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090107 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -lpq -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.so

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/src/_build'
  Running setup.py install for dj-database-url

Successfully installed Django psycopg2 dj-database-url
Cleaning up...
```

Thanks a ton for any help!!

Comment: Do you have postgres installed on your local machine?

Comment: yes bkz I can run -->

ahmad@ubuntu:~$ su postgres
postgres@ubuntu:/home/ahmad$ service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server
   ...done.

Comment: That pip install output doesn't contain any errors - it says that psycopg2 installed correctly and the extension for postgresql was built and installed ok. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: when I launch my django apps on heroku they crash from the get go, they automaticall start with an error although they run fine locally. I get some sort of issue w/ DATABASES['default'] (i closed the error window :()... i thought psycopg2 issue might be the root cause.

Comment: Did you use `python-psycopg2` for the package name, or `psycopg2`?

Comment: I used python-psycopg2 but it would say "Picking 'psycopg2' as source package instead of 'python-psycopg2' " then on the following line of the terminal i get "E: Unable to find a source package for psycopg2"

Comment: to all, thanks a ton for your time and help btw, really appreciate it

Comment: Can you do `sudo apt-get update` and try again? What does your  `/etc/apt/sources.list` file contain?

Comment: I ran sudo apt-get update, everything was still the same...but i seem to have gotten my django app running on heroku w/out needing to fix this! :)

Comment: What does `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep deb-src` return?

Comment: cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep deb-src returned nothing...

Comment: That explains why you are seeing `E: Unable to find a source package for psycopg2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit your sources.list file (normally found in `/etc/apt/sources.list`) and add a `deb-src` entry for each corresponding `deb` line.

> deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
>
> deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted **#Add this line**
>
> deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
>
> deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted **#Add this line**

The difference between the two:

- `deb`: These repositories contain binaries or precompiled packages.
  These repositories are required for most users.
- `deb-src`: These repositories contain the source code of the
  packages. Useful for developers.

Now try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep psycopg2
```

Answer (score 1):

I turns out that the reason my heroku django apps were crashing from the get-go was because i had these lines of codes,

DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

then

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

I just rearranged the order of them so that this DATABASES['default'] comes after the creation of the dictionary....

my apps were crashing bkz i was trying to initialize a dictionary that didn't exist yet :(

I didn't see the error on my pc bkz i was too naive/arrogant abt running the runserver command to see if i get the django "it works" page bkz i didn't think i tampered w/anything... while in reality i was using erroneous python code from following the heorku tutorial blindly.

I'm still not sure whats up with all that psycopg stuff and can't find source, and gcc junk but my django apps are running fine for now...

Thanks :)